# Invalid Grant on different tenant

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm very new in WSO2 AM and I have this scenario:

I create a new tenant on carbon, on that new tenant I create a JDBC userstore, my users are listed in the "Identity > Users and Roles" tab correctly, then I create a new Service Provider with OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration and grant_type password.

When I want to test my configuration (¿generate a new token?) via Postman > Get New Access Token like the following Image:

[image]

When I request the token the answer is

> {"error_description":"Users in the tenant domain : **carbon.super** do
>   not have access to application
>   *myapplication*","error":"invalid_grant"}

I don't understand why it tries to use the carbon.super domain when I'm using my new domain in the Access Token URL.

Searching in Google I found that when I enable my Service Provider like a "SaaS Application" can work, but when I do it the new response is:

> {"error_description":"Authentication failed for
>   nicolas_webfile","error":"invalid_grant"}

I'm using WSO2 API Manager 2.6.0

Comment: what are you going to do with the token?

Comment: @Bee If all goes well I'll implement this in the application but I will use various domains/tenants for different authentication modules, by now I'm just testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using API Manager, change the request as below.

```
URL: http://localhost:8243/token
Username: user@webfile.com
```

Comment: When I used user@webfile.com in the Username field, everything worked well. Do you know if is there a way to avoid the domain?

Comment: No, that's how it works. But you can append the domain when you make the request from the application so that the user doesn't have to provide the domain with the username.